# Cropping a screenshot in swift

Tags: swift, uiimage, screenshot, cgimage

I am trying to take a screenshot of the screen and crop a part out of that screenshot.
the screenshot part is working perfect, but I can't make the cropping part work.

```
var image = self.view?.pb_takeSnapshot()

let croprect = CGRectMake(view.bounds.width/2, view.bounds.height/3.8, 
               view.bounds.width/2,    view.bounds.height/3.5)

    var imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(CGImage(image), croprect) //Error: CGImage cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers
    var croppedImage = UIImage(CGImage: imageRef)
```

function that takes the screenshot:

```
func pb_takeSnapshot() -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale);

    self.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)

    // old style: self.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

My question: is there a way to do this without using CGImage, or is there a simple way to convert an UIImage to a CGImage?

Comment: Try......`image.CGImage`?

Comment: Error: UIImage? does not have a member named CGImage

Comment: I see, it's an optional! So `image?.CGImage`

Comment: it had to be image?.CGImage , thank you

Comment: It seems like you could also just modify your function to pass in the cropping variable (croprect) and use it in place of self.bounds and it would return a cropped image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIImage` in most cases contains a `CGImage` that you can directly access.

In your case `image` is set using Optional Chaining and is of type `UIImage?` so you would need:

`UIImage?.CGImage`

to access the `CGImage`

Comment: one quick question: frame.size in GameScene has other  values than view.bounds in GameviewController. What can I use in gameviewcontroller to get same values as frame.size in gamescene?

Comment: Can you access the GameScene from GameViewController? If not I can't really help you cuz I'm not too familiar with SceneKit/SpriteKit :( Post a new question!